# Update sem where

Tags: android, firebase

Como fazer um incremento apenas no child **periodo** de todos os alunos cadastrados no Firebase?

Ex.: no SQL, eu usaria:

```
UPDATE alunos
SET periodo = periodo + 1
```

Atualizando todos os alunos para seu período posterior. Como posso fazer no Firebase?

Comment: Tiago, edite sua pergunta e a sua edição, que foi a solução, adicione como resposta à esta pergunta.

Comment: @Ismael pronto. Obrigado pela sugestão! Sou novo como usuário no stack.

Comment: @Henrique pronto. Obrigado pela sugestão! Sou novo como usuário no stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui realizar o que precisava adaptando o código abaixo

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String true = "true";
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("SubmitCheck").getRef().setValue(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162528/how-to-set-value-to-all-childs-data-in-firebase-database